# Using DISTINCT in window function with OVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, window-functions

I'm trying to migrate a query from Oracle to SQL Server 2014.

Here is my query which works great in Oracle:

```
select
count(distinct A) over (partition by B) / count(*) over() as A_B
from MyTable
```

Here is the error i got after tried to run this query in SQL Server 2014.

```
Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause
```

Anyone know what is the problem? Is such as kind of query possible in SQL Server?
Please advise.

Comment: Do yo actually need one row in the result for every row in `MyTable`? Or are distinct rows enough? And you don't need to consider the division by zero error if there are *no* rows in `MyTable`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Anyone know what is the problem? Is such as kind of query possible in
>   SQL Server?

No it isn't currently implemented. See the following connect item request.

[OVER clause enhancement request - DISTINCT clause for aggregate functions](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32890510-over-clause-enhancement-request-distinct-clause)

Another possible variant would be

```
SELECT M.A,
       M.B,
       T.A_B
FROM   MyTable M
       JOIN (SELECT CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT A) AS NUMERIC(18,8)) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS A_B,
                    B
             FROM   MyTable
             GROUP  BY B) T
         ON EXISTS (SELECT M.B INTERSECT SELECT T.B)
```

the cast to `NUMERIC` is there to avoid integer division. The reason for the join clause is [explained here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx).

It can be replaced with `ON M.B = T.B OR (M.B IS NULL AND T.B IS NULL)` if preferred (or simply `ON M.B = T.B` if the `B` column is not nullable).

Answer (score 23):

This gives the distinct count(*) for A partitioned by B:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by B order by A) 
+ dense_rank() over (partition by B order by A desc) 
- 1
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I suppose it should have a disclaimer that it works when `A` is non-nullable only (as I think it counts nulls as well).

Comment: It should be `abs(dense_rank - dense_rank) + 1` I believe.

Comment: This also works without any partitioning, just over (order by A) where A is the column you want to distinctly count.

Answer (score 8):

You can take the max value of `dense_rank()` to get the distinct count of A partitioned by B.

To take care of the case where A can have null values you can use `first_value` to figure out if a null is present in the partition or not and then subtract 1 if it is as suggested by Martin Smith in the comment.

```
select (max(T.DenseRankA) over(partition by T.B) - 
          cast(iif(T.FirstA is null, 1, 0) as numeric(18, 8))) / T.TotalCount as A_B
from (
     select dense_rank() over(partition by T.B order by T.A) DenseRankA,
            first_value(T.A) over(partition by T.B order by T.A) as FirstA,
            count(*) over() as TotalCount,
            T.A,
            T.B
     from MyTable as T
     ) as T
```

Answer (score 5):

Try doing a subquery, grouping by A, B, and including the count. Then in your outer query, your count(distinct) becomes a regular count, and your count(*) becomes a sum(cnt).

```
select
count(A) over (partition by B) * 1.0 / 
    sum(cnt) over() as A_B
from
(select A, B, count(*) as cnt
 from MyTable
 group by A, B) as partial;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server for now does not allow using `Distinct` with windowed functions.

But once you remember how windowed functions work (that is: they're applied to result set of the query), you can work around that:

```
select B,
min(count(distinct A)) over (partition by B) / max(count(*)) over() as A_B
from MyTable
group by B
```