# Running ratio of unique counts to total counts

Tags: sql-server, running-totals

Any ideas on how to code a running ratio of counts (unique and total) for ordered observations (rows) in t-SQL (SQL Server 2017 Community Edition or higher)?

Given a data set, which is necessarily ordered (Ex. a time series indexed/ordered by date):

```
CREATE TABLE #x (dt DATE, Name VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO #x VALUES
('2012-01-01', 'a'),('2012-01-02', 'b'),('2012-01-03', 'c'),
('2012-01-04', 'a'),('2012-01-05', 'b'),('2012-01-06', 'd'),
('2012-01-07', 'a'),('2012-01-08', 'b'),('2012-01-09', 'e'),('2012-01-10', 'e');
```

So, given columns `Dt` and `Names`, I need the output `Ratio` below. For clarity, I also included output columns `UCnt` that counts unique names to date (i.e. a restricted running count) and `TCnt` counts all names to date (i.e. a simple running count). The output `Ratio` field is a just a running proportion of the two.

```
Dt          Name    UCnt    TCnt    Ratio
2012-01-01  a       1       1       1.000
2012-01-02  b       2       2       1.000
2012-01-03  c       3       3       1.000
2012-01-04  a       3       4       0.750
2012-01-05  b       3       5       0.600
2012-01-06  d       4       6       0.666
2012-01-07  a       4       7       0.571
2012-01-08  b       4       8       0.500
2012-01-09  e       5       9       0.555
2012-01-10  e       5       10      0.500
```

Comment: Related question that you already found: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89031/using-distinct-in-window-function-with-over

Comment: Thanks Joe. Yes, somewhat related, but my question accounts for ordered observations and for a running (not fixed) denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lamak. The `OUTER APPLY` ran for 2+ hours (~1MM rows); I had to kill it. Here is my solution that takes ~30 sec on the same-size table.

```
WITH y AS (-- count dupped Names and each observation
    SELECT dt, Name,
    UCnt_=COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Dt), 
    TCnt=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dt)
    FROM #x
),
z AS (-- count unique Names only
    SELECT *,
    UCnt=SUM(CASE WHEN UCnt_>1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Dt) 
    FROM y
)
SELECT Dt, Name, UCnt_, UCnt, TCnt, Ratio=UCnt/1.0/TCnt
FROM z
ORDER BY Dt
```

The output:

```
Dt          Name    UCnt_   UCnt    TCnt    Ratio
2012-01-01  a       1       1       1       1.000
2012-01-02  b       1       2       2       1.000
2012-01-03  c       1       3       3       1.000
2012-01-04  a       2       3       4       0.750
2012-01-05  b       2       3       5       0.600
2012-01-06  d       1       4       6       0.666
2012-01-07  a       3       4       7       0.571
2012-01-08  b       3       4       8       0.500
2012-01-09  e       1       5       9       0.555
2012-01-10  e       2       5       10      0.500
```

Answer (score 4):

A combination of `OUTER APPLY` and `ROW_NUMBER` seems to do the trick:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            Tot_Cnt = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dt)
    FROM #x
)
SELECT  A.dt,
        A.[Name],
        B.Unq_Cnt,
        A.Tot_Cnt,
        Ratio_of_Cnts = CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,4),B.Unq_Cnt)/A.Tot_Cnt 
FROM CTE A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT Unq_Cnt = COUNT(DISTINCT [Name]) 
             FROM CTE
             WHERE dt <= A.dt) B
;
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f62880f6b5280c412cd463f88ec4e02a) of this.